# Biblical evidence for not eating bread on passover?

Tags: food, passover, sources-mekorot, chametz-leaven, pentateuch-chumash

Can someone cite lines from the Torah that specify what Jews should eat during Passover?  I'm aware that Jews don't eat leavened bread during Passover.  Where does this rule come from?

Comment: New user, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please edit [your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1322/user176105) and give yourself a name, unless you have some special attachment to the number 176105. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chametz#Torah_related_sources) on Chametz (leaven):

> The Torah has several commandments governing chametz during Passover:
>
> - The positive commandment to remove all chametz from one's home ([Exodus 12:15](http://bibref.hebtools.com/?book=%20Exodus&verse=12:15&src=HE)).
> - Not to possess chametz in one's domain. ([Exodus 12:19](http://bibref.hebtools.com/?book=%20Exodus&verse=12:19&src=HE), [Deuteronomy 16:4](http://bibref.hebtools.com/?book=%20Deuteronomy&verse=16:4&src=HE)).
> - Not to eat chametz, or mixtures containing chametz ([Exodus 13:3](http://bibref.hebtools.com/?book=%20Exodus&verse=13:3&src=HE), [Exodus 12:20](http://bibref.hebtools.com/?book=%20Exodus&verse=12:20&src=HE), [Deuteronomy 16:3](http://bibref.hebtools.com/?book=%20Deuteronomy&verse=16:3&src=HE)).

Comment: thanks.  i read the translation in the links you provided and it only says not to eat "bread."  It doesn't say anything about ice cream or those other foods that are forbidden

Comment: Ex. 12:18-19 includes the prohibition to eat nothing that is "leavened".  This prohibition is broader than just bread.

Comment: @MonicaCellio ice cream isn't leavened

Comment: The reason some ice cream brands and other foods are deemed not Kosher for Passover is because they are produced in factories that don't necessarily have supervision for that sort of thing and there is no way to know whether a crumb of something leavened ended up in the batch (i.e. An ice cream company that makes a "Cookies and cream" flavor might use the same machinery between different batches, etc.)

Comment: @Chaim thanks. but say I could somehow ensure no crumbs got into the ice cream.  would that be ok?  also, is corn syrup ok?

Comment: Technically if you *know* that the ice cream is leaven-free then yes. However if it was made in plant it is more complicated. It's particularly difficult in our current era to ascertain where most food products actually come from so all these things would need to be factored in, hence there being organizations that oversee the production of food. But yes, if you were to take your own milk and a clean ice-cream maker you could your own kosher-for-passover ice cream

Comment: Corn-syrup is a different story. Corn is among the grains known as "kitnyot" were are rabbinically forbidden to Ashenazi Jews because they are grain substitutes. Grains like rice and corn are examples. However, these are *not* leaven. (In fact there is a discussion in the Talmud about using rice matza!) But these were established by the rabbis of Ashenazi Jewry as a fence around the Torah.

Since corn syrup is a derivative of corn, we are cautious to avoid it as well and as such products containing corn syrup are generally deemed "not kosher for Passover".

Comment: There's a discussion in Pesachim (35a IIRC) of rice and millet, with the rabbis there permitting them.  Somewhere between then and the Ashkenazic kitniyot ruling they became forbidden (for Ashkenazim).

Comment: @user176105 FWIW, there are many brands of ice cream, candies, even cookies and cake, which are prepared especially kosher for passover, and are available in an increasing amount of supermarkets throughout North America (and of course, Israel)  When it comes to unleavened copies of cookies and cake, there are two main ways to achieve this.  One is matzah meal.  We have a rule that once grain flour is baked into matzah, it can't become chametz.  So, we take matzah, grind it down finely, and use that to "bake".  Another way is to use potato starch.  Neither are 100% like year-round products.

Comment: Thank you everyone for these detailed answers. It seems those torah lines only forbid anything "leavened," specifically bread, but there is also a line that says not to eat anything leavened.  If I have this correct, corn-syrup and other grain substitutes are not forbidden by the Torah, but rather by some Rabbis?

Comment: @kirby the Torah forbids deviating from the rulings of our rabbis.

Comment: @yoel thanks.  can you cite the Torah line that mentions not deviating from the rulings of rabbis?

Comment: @kirby [Devorim 17:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0517.htm#11).

Comment: @yoel who is the "they"?  Is it the "priests the Levites"?

Comment: @kirby the "judges", who are rabbis from Moshe Rabbenu on down.

Comment: @yoel post-Talmud rabbis do not have (real) smicha and cannot enact fences considered "derabbonons", which is what the pasuk is talking about. Corn syrup on pesach is not assur miderabannan, rather it is kept as a minhog. Our rabbis today do not form a direct link with Moses (see intro to rambam's yad hachazukuh)

Answer (score 2):

It's in the book of [Shemos (Exodus), 12:18-19](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm)

Comment: ACDN..................

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I was one of the ACDNs, and I thought the poor quality of the answer was so evident on reading it that no explanation was necessary. In fact, I still think so. I'm very surprised that this got four upvotes.

Comment: @msh210 I disagree. The question asks "Where is the source" and this attempts to answer it. It's not the clearest, and would do well to quote the verses here, but it's not downvote-worthy IMO. And if it is, it certainly should be commented on so Chaim can improve it (again, IMO).

Comment: @msh210 Oh, and you might want to remove the "N" from your "ACDN" because that one stands for "ninja"

Comment: @HodofHod, there are too many chapters in Exodus for me to consider this answer worth anything at all.